# Regular Expressions to select all the text that is “not”: Curly brackets {} and whats between them?

Tags: regex, libreoffice

if I have a text like this:

**Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur {adipiscing elit bghy}. Ftoam sem augue {tincidunt sit amet}, volutpat vel, egestas quis {lacus gonec mattis}. nisi et lacinia vehicula, lectus mi {luctus urna eu molestie diam lectus vel eros}. Donec a massa neque.**

What is the Regular Expressions to select **all the text that is “not”**: Curly brackets {} and whats between them?

This Regular Expressions select Curly brackets {} and what is between them. What I want is: all the text that is “not”: Curly brackets {} and whats between them.

```
\{[^}]*\}
```

Comment: Please mention tool/lang you're using. In PCRE you could use e.g. [`{[^}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)|[^{]+`](https://regex101.com/r/DPMxdi/2) else an idea is to [match what you don't want but capture what you need](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): [`{[^}]*}*|([^{]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/TYXZJU/2)

Comment: Then use `\{[^{}]*}|([^{}]+)` and replace with `$1` (or `\1`).

Comment: Thanks. I am using “find and replace” in LibreOffice, it supported: ICU’s Regular Expressions package: The regular expression patterns and behavior are based on Perl’s regular expressions. The C++ programming API for using ICU regular expressions is loosely based on the JDK 1.4 package java.util.regex, with some extensions to adapt it for use in a C++ environment.

{[^}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)|[^{]+
This one works very well in https://regex101.com/
but not in LibreOffice.

Comment: Thanks. \{[^{}]*}|([^{}]+)  didn't work in LibreOffice.
Notice that what I want is “only selecting - highlighting” all the text that is “not”: Curly brackets {} and whats between them. 
I do not want to replace it.

Comment: If this is a Java based regex, worth a try: [`[^}{]++(?=\{|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/x3kCOJ/1)

Comment: [^}{]++(?=\{|$) 
work like a charm in LibreOffice !
Thanks bobble bubble .. And Thanks for others for there suggestion.

Comment: @BYMGroub You're welcome! I put a slightly shorter negative variant as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and *possessive* quantifier:

```
[^}{]++(?!\})
```

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/x3kCOJ/2)

- `[^}{]` matches [any character besides](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) the braces
- `++` [possessively](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) (without giving back) *one or more* times
- `(?!\})` only match those *not followed by* a closing brace

Answer (score 0):

You did not tag with any tool or prgramming language, but you *did* tag with regex replacement.  Assuming you can do a regex replacement, use the following find and replace:

```
Find:     \s*\{.*?\}\s*
Replace: (single space)
```

The regex replacement strategy is to remove all terms in curly braces.  Note that you might also need to trim whitespace from the start/end, as the above replacement could leave dangling whitespace there.

Here is a working [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vhPEAD/1).

If you *can't* do a replacement, you could try finding on the following regex pattern:

```
(?<=[^\S{])\w+[,;:.]?(?: \w+[,;:.]?(?=[^\S}]))*
```

This matches one or more terms, possibly separated by punctuation.  It insists that the first and last term are not surrounded by `{...}`.

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is “only selecting” all the text that is “not”: Curly brackets {} and whats between them. I do not want to replace it or delete it.

Comment: @BYMGroub [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kc6UqG/1) for one option.